# Office 365 vbaproject.otm Outlook folder doesn't exist, but does...?

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, office365

We have an integration for one of our clients that makes use of a 'vbaproject.otm' file.

As part of a new PC configuration I was running through the normal setup process of dropping the vbaproject.otm into the user's roaming profile under %appdata%\Microsoft\Outlook, when I noticed that the folder hadn't been created although Outlook had been installed and run.

Thinking nothing of it, I create the folder and dropped the file in.  When I restarted Office 365 Outlook I went to add toolbar buttons for the macro to find the macro wasn't available.  I checked all the usual configuration options (Trust centers etc etc) and everything was fine.

I used the 'Go' button on the Options\Add-ins tab to 'Add' a new plugin and dropped up a folder to the 'Microsoft' directory and the 'Outlook' folder was there.  Switching from 'Executable Files' to 'All files' the contents of the folder were completely different to the folder I'd created manually, and did NOT contain the VBA Project file!

The address bar in the options dialog, and a separate Windows explorer window matched EXACTLY, yet the folder contents were different!

I deleted the folder I'd created, and tried to browse to the path shown in the Outlook options windows using the separate explorer window and got (as expected) a 'The path does not exist' message.  I tried to copy and paste the VBA project file from the separate window into in the options dialog, and got a 'File does not exist' message.

In despair, I rebooted the PC and repeated the above, and the file finally copied.  (And everything from there on in was normal).

But I can't explain WHY there is a folder under the users roaming profile that Outlook can see, but the user can't?

Right-clicking on the folder in the options dialog to get the security information shows the correct permissions, and the user is a local PC administrator...?

Has anyone seen this before, or can explain what's going on?!?!?

***Point of note:***

This PC is the only PC in the building that has never had any other version of Office on it other than Office 365.  All others have had Office 2010 or above installed in the past.

Comment: This is difficult to check, we do not know what you have done, such a problem in other computers will happen?

Comment: All other PCs in the building are existing installations that started with a version of Office prior to Office 365.  This is the first PC that has only had Office 365 installed.